# C# how to get the Windows monitor name

Tags: c#, windows, pinvoke

I'm trying to make a function that displays all display and monitor names.
But the 2nd time I call enumDisplayDevices, there's an error if the first argument is lpDisplayDevice.DeviceName.  I know it's the first argument becuase if it's set to "IntPtr.Zero" instead, there is no error.

I cannot find another example of how to do this in C#.

```
    public static void show_display_devices()
    {
        DISPLAY_DEVICE lpDisplayDevice = new DISPLAY_DEVICE(0);     // OUT
        int devNum = 0;
        while(true)
        {
            bool success = EnumDisplayDevices( IntPtr.Zero,  devNum,  ref lpDisplayDevice,  0);
            if( !success )
                break;

            Console.WriteLine("\ndevNum =" + devNum);
            Console.WriteLine("cb =" + lpDisplayDevice.cb);
            Console.WriteLine("DeviceID =" + lpDisplayDevice.DeviceID);
            Console.WriteLine("DeviceKey =" + lpDisplayDevice.DeviceKey);
            Console.WriteLine("DeviceName =" + lpDisplayDevice.DeviceName.Trim());
            Console.WriteLine("DeviceString =" + lpDisplayDevice.DeviceString.Trim());
            // Show monitor name:
            DISPLAY_DEVICE monitor_name = new DISPLAY_DEVICE(0);        // OUT

               >>>>>>>>>>>   NEXT LINE HAS ERROR:  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            EnumDisplayDevices(lpDisplayDevice.DeviceName, 0, ref monitor_name, 0);  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  "lpDisplayDevice.DeviceName" causes error  <<<<<<
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - CAUSES ERROR <<<<<<

            Console.WriteLine("Monitor name =" + lpDisplayDevice.DeviceString.Trim());

            ++devNum;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its kind of useless, as I never saw a installation where the monitor was properly installed with its name displayed correctly in the Device Manager. "Generic Plug and Play Monitor" is the monitor name you will find in 99.9% of all computers your program run.

Comment: I think your question ought to include your definition for the DISPLAY_DEVICE structure and the EnumDisplayDevices method.  The error might be related to how particular fields or function arguments are being marshaled.  Since the first argument to EnumDisplayDevices is an LPCTSTR, which is typically handled as a C# string argument, I suspect you might have a type mismatch here.

Comment: Havenard:  In our product, when our known HDMI monitor is connected, I read the monitor name to determine if the monitor is connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the declaration "private static extern bool EnumDisplayDevices()".  I changed lpDevice from IntPtr to string, and it works for me.

The source code below produces the following in the Output window:

devNum =0
cb =424
DeviceID =PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_0402&SUBSYS_0440196E&REV_A1
DeviceKey =\Registry\Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video{B757E378-AF2E-4826-BA9E-927C5B81B139}\0000
DeviceName =\.\DISPLAY1
DeviceString =NVIDIA GeForce 8600 GT
The thread 'RunPowerStatusMonitor Thread' (0x2108) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Monitor name =Generic PnP Monitor

devNum =1
cb =424
DeviceID =PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_0402&SUBSYS_0440196E&REV_A1
DeviceKey =\Registry\Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video{B757E378-AF2E-4826-BA9E-927C5B81B139}\0001
DeviceName =\.\DISPLAY2
DeviceString =NVIDIA GeForce 8600 GT
Monitor name =Generic PnP Monitor

```
        public static void show_display_devices()
    {
        DISPLAY_DEVICE lpDisplayDevice = new DISPLAY_DEVICE(0);     // OUT
            DISPLAY_DEVICE monitor_name = new DISPLAY_DEVICE(0);        // OUT

        int devNum = 0;
        while (EnumDisplayDevices(null, devNum, ref lpDisplayDevice, 0))
        {

            Console.WriteLine("\ndevNum =" + devNum);
            Console.WriteLine("cb =" + lpDisplayDevice.cb);
            Console.WriteLine("DeviceID =" + lpDisplayDevice.DeviceID);
            Console.WriteLine("DeviceKey =" + lpDisplayDevice.DeviceKey);
            Console.WriteLine("DeviceName =" + lpDisplayDevice.DeviceName.Trim());
            Console.WriteLine("DeviceString =" + lpDisplayDevice.DeviceString.Trim());
            // Show monitor name:



            EnumDisplayDevices( lpDisplayDevice.DeviceName, 0, ref monitor_name, 0);
            Console.WriteLine("Monitor name =" + monitor_name.DeviceString.Trim());

            ++devNum;
        }
    }

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern bool EnumDisplayDevices(
        string lpDevice, int iDevNum,
        ref DISPLAY_DEVICE lpDisplayDevice, int dwFlags);




    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct DISPLAY_DEVICE
    {
        public int cb;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
        public string DeviceName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
        public string DeviceString;
        public int StateFlags;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
        public string DeviceID;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
        public string DeviceKey;

        public DISPLAY_DEVICE(int flags)
        {
            cb = 0;
            StateFlags = flags;
            DeviceName = new string((char)32, 32);
            DeviceString = new string((char)32, 128);
            DeviceID = new string((char)32, 128);
            DeviceKey = new string((char)32, 128);
            cb = Marshal.SizeOf(this);
        }
    }
```

Comment: OK, I see. Too bad you did not include the code that counted. Another time I suggest you include a complete program with all the referenced code. I should have read the docs more closely. You clearly knew all about the second call.

Comment: In fact it's very hard to work the details out from the docs. I wish you'd put it all in the question. Would have saved me some time.

Comment: Very sorry.  I'm new to C#, and originally believed the bug was in the function, not the original declaration which I got from an Internet example.  But I don't understand why someone would vote down a working solution. ??