# Display Count (Inc. Disabled Displays)

Tags: c#

Hello everyone new to stackoverflow.com. Not sure how would question be asked here, but doing my best. Done, quite some research on subject, but couldn't find a single thing to resolve the detection.

Example Case:
Trying to identify count of active AND disabled displays in Windows 7-10 systems.

Code GPU[Availability]:

```
        private int MonCount;
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern bool EnumDisplayDevices(
        string lpDevice, int iDevNum,
        ref DISPLAY_DEVICE lpDisplayDevice, int dwFlags);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct DISPLAY_DEVICE
    {
        public int cb;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
        public string DeviceName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
        public string DeviceString;
        public int StateFlags;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
        public string DeviceID;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
        public string DeviceKey;

        public DISPLAY_DEVICE(int flags)
        {
            cb = 0;
            StateFlags = flags;
            DeviceName = new string((char)32, 32);
            DeviceString = new string((char)32, 128);
            DeviceID = new string((char)32, 128);
            DeviceKey = new string((char)32, 128);
            cb = Marshal.SizeOf(this);
        }
    }
    public void MonitorCheck()
    {
        DISPLAY_DEVICE lpDisplayDevice = new DISPLAY_DEVICE(0);     // OUT
        DISPLAY_DEVICE monitor_name = new DISPLAY_DEVICE(0);        // OUT

        int devNum = 0;
        while (EnumDisplayDevices(null, devNum, ref lpDisplayDevice, 0))
        {

            listBox1.Items.Add("\ndevNum =" + devNum);
            listBox1.Items.Add("cb =" + lpDisplayDevice.cb);
            listBox1.Items.Add("DeviceID =" + lpDisplayDevice.DeviceID);
            listBox1.Items.Add("DeviceKey =" + lpDisplayDevice.DeviceKey);
            listBox1.Items.Add("DeviceName =" + lpDisplayDevice.DeviceName.Trim());
            listBox1.Items.Add("DeviceString =" + lpDisplayDevice.DeviceString.Trim());
            // Show monitor name:
            EnumDisplayDevices(lpDisplayDevice.DeviceName, 0, ref monitor_name, 0);
            listBox1.Items.Add("Monitor name =" + monitor_name.DeviceString.Trim());
            ++devNum;
        }
    }
```

Source: [C# how to get the Windows monitor name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199982/c-sharp-how-to-get-the-windows-monitor-name)

Return: All attachable monitors by Graphic Adapter Information. Count is always as how many monitors can be attached in display adapter.

Code Active Displays:

```
Screen.AllScreens.Count();
```

Return: Active monitor count.

Problem:

If GPU Adapter has 3 outputs:
* Above GPU[Availability] code returns: 3
(no matter how many displays are attached to it.)

If 2 Monitors are attached (Example: Laptop Monitor + External HDMI Monitor), but display setup is set to: Laptop Monitor ONLY (External HDMI Monitor is not active) -> Active Displays code Returns: 1

**Question**:

How do I return 2 as there is non-active display and active display attached (Laptop Monitor + Non-active External Monitor)?

**Solutions**:

There's few ideas how to resolve this:

1. Activate all displays by extending them and simply redo: `Screen.AllScreens.Count();`

Idea:
Compare output of GPU[Availability] output and count all which gives any value as `monitor_name.DeviceString.Trim()` (However, I've tested this at desktop having NVIDIA adapter: outcome is null, but in laptop Intel HD adapter: output is always "Generic PnP-Monitor", so, this is no solution).

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me... Never though to use all 3 methods to solve problem. (Seems damn     hard to get code to work in code tags here at forums.

- Maximum attachable displays
- Currently attached displays
- Currently Active displays

**Solution:**

Hmm, can't seem to be able to attach my code to stackoverflow reply, so:

[Pastebin: Monitors counting](http://pastebin.com/Le67NKaL)